# Can I get list of recently created users from azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My requirement is to get the list of recently created users based on to use query parameters to implement filters on it but unfortunately it didn't worked for me.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

This is how I was trying to achieve this, but it was giving me syntax error I don't know why, instead it should give error like "createdDateTime" is not supported as query parameter.

Can anyone help me to get list of recently created users based on parameter createdDateTime or any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `ge` with Azure AD resources. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#filter-parameter):

> Note: The following `$filter` operators are not supported for Azure AD resources: `ne`, `gt`, `ge`, `lt`, `le`, and `not`. The `contains` string operator is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

If you want to track changes to the AAD Users, you should use [Deltas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).